# Как передавать в HTTP-заголовке данные авторизации для Яндекс API?

Tags: python, яндекс-маркет

Раньше подключался к API Яндекса query-параметре запроса. С недавнего времени этот способ они отключили в целях безопасности. Теперь необходимо

[Инструкция Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/market/partner-marketplace-cd/doc/dg/concepts/authorization.html)

> В запросах к партнерскому API необходимо указывать: OAuth-токен в
> параметре oauth_token; идентификатор приложения в параметре
> oauth_client_id. Авторизационные данные передаются в HTTP-заголовке
> Authorization:
>
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="авторизационный_токен",
> oauth_client_id="идентификатор_приложения"

Пробую так:

```
import requests

HEADERS = {                                                                                                                               
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-en,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',

    'Connection': 'keep-close',

    'Authorization': 'OAuth',
    'oauth_token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    'oauth_client_id': 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'}      

print (requests.get('https://api.partner.market.yandex.ru/v2/models/605238026/offers.json',headers=HEADERS))
```

получаю
<Response [401]>

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос?

Comment: Ну, там же есть пример, `oauth_token` и `oauth_client_id` передаются в параметре `Authorization`. Примерно так: `'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_client_id="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"'`

Comment: И ключи смените, в истории правок они светятся.

Comment: Спасибо большое! заработало! )))

Comment: Не забывайте правильные подходящие ответы отмечать галочкой. =)

Comment: Извините, я тут впервые...
Галочку нашел, но рядом с вашим ответом ее почему-то нет. ((

Comment: Если это важно. Добавьте еще один ответ, и я его отмечу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HEADERS = {                                                                                                                               
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-en,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',

    'Connection': 'keep-close',

    'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_token="авторизационный_токен", oauth_client_id="идентификатор_приложения"'}
```

`Authorization` - это заголовок. `OAuth` (тип авторизации) и все остальное - его значение.
[HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).

Comment: Да, так и есть, не мог правильный синтаксис сделать на это! спасибо большое!!!